# Proving $|x|+|y|+|z| ≤ |x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|$ for all real $x$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> We need to prove that for all real $x,y,z$
>
> $$|x|+|y|+|z| ≤ |x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+|z+x-y|$$
> Source [ISI entrance examination](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf) sample questions

I don't know how to solve in mod form so I thought about squaring and removing the mod, but the mod on RHS still persists.

I believe there can be a different approach to it, I would like to have some **hints** on how to do approach it.

Comment: Im not really sure it would work, but i think we could use triangle inequality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$$2x=(x+y-z)+(x+z-y) \implies x=\frac{x+y-z}{2}+\frac{x+z-y}{2}$$
Now repeat the process for $y$ and $z$ and use the triangle inequality trice

Answer (score 4):

write $A=x+y-z, B=y+z-x, C=x+z-y$. Then $A+B+C=x+y+z$ which is not so useful. Instead use
$$A+B = 2y,\\B+C=2z,\\C+A=2x$$
and
so
\begin{align}
|x|+|y|+|z| &= \frac{|A+B|+|B+C|+|C+A|}2 
\\
&\le \frac{|A|+|B| + |B| + |C| + |C| + |A|}2 
\\
&= |A|+|B|+|C|
\\
&=|x+y-z|+|y+z-x|+ |x+z-y|.
\end{align}